Cannot install TensorFlow gpu
Sorry for my bad English. I'm on Windows 11 and have CUDA 11.8
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2022 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Sep_21_10:41:10_Pacific_Daylight_Time_2022
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.8, V11.8.89
Build cuda_11.8.r11.8/compiler.31833905_0```

I also installed WSL2
NAME      STATE           VERSION

* Ubuntu    Stopped         2

Now I want to install TensorFlow for gpu but everytime i run pip install tensorflow[and-cuda] it give me an error
Collecting tensorflow\[and-cuda\]
Using cached tensorflow-2.16.1-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (3.5 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-intel==2.16.1 in c:\\users\\nguye\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python312\\lib\\site-packages (from tensorflow\[and-cuda\]) (2.16.1)
Collecting nvidia-cublas-cu12==12.3.4.1 (from tensorflow\[and-cuda\])
Using cached nvidia_cublas_cu12-12.3.4.1-py3-none-win_amd64.whl.metadata (1.5 kB)
Collecting nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu12==12.3.101 (from tensorflow\[and-cuda\])
Using cached nvidia_cuda_cupti_cu12-12.3.101-py3-none-win_amd64.whl.metadata (1.6 kB)
Collecting nvidia-cuda-nvcc-cu12==12.3.107 (from tensorflow\[and-cuda\])
Using cached nvidia_cuda_nvcc_cu12-12.3.107-py3-none-win_amd64.whl.metadata (1.5 kB)
Collecting nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu12==12.3.107 (from tensorflow\[and-cuda\])
Using cached nvidia_cuda_nvrtc_cu12-12.3.107-py3-none-win_amd64.whl.metadata (1.5 kB)
Collecting nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu12==12.3.101 (from tensorflow\[and-cuda\])
Using cached nvidia_cuda_runtime_cu12-12.3.101-py3-none-win_amd64.whl.metadata (1.5 kB)
Collecting nvidia-cudnn-cu12==8.9.7.29 (from tensorflow\[and-cuda\])
Using cached nvidia_cudnn_cu12-8.9.7.29-py3-none-win_amd64.whl.metadata (1.6 kB)
Collecting nvidia-cufft-cu12==11.0.12.1 (from tensorflow\[and-cuda\])
Using cached nvidia_cufft_cu12-11.0.12.1-py3-none-win_amd64.whl.metadata (1.5 kB)
Collecting nvidia-curand-cu12==10.3.4.107 (from tensorflow\[and-cuda\])
Using cached nvidia_curand_cu12-10.3.4.107-py3-none-win_amd64.whl.metadata (1.5 kB)
Collecting nvidia-cusolver-cu12==11.5.4.101 (from tensorflow\[and-cuda\])
Using cached nvidia_cusolver_cu12-11.5.4.101-py3-none-win_amd64.whl.metadata (1.6 kB)
Collecting nvidia-cusparse-cu12==12.2.0.103 (from tensorflow\[and-cuda\])
Using cached nvidia_cusparse_cu12-12.2.0.103-py3-none-win_amd64.whl.metadata (1.6 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of tensorflow\[and-cuda\] to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement nvidia-nccl-cu12==2.19.3; extra == "and-cuda" (from tensorflow\[and-cuda\]) (from versions: 0.0.1.dev5)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for nvidia-nccl-cu12==2.19.3; extra == "and-cuda"

It took me very lot of time but i still didn't know how to fix it. Someone please help me!
I got an error but didn't know how to fix. I expect a helpfull answer

Hi@Phuc Nguyen, You're encountering an issue with installing TensorFlow with GPU support due to an unavailable package nvidia-nccl-cu12==2.19.3.,Before proceeding, ensure that you have the correct versions of CUDA and cuDNN installed. TensorFlow 2.16.1 (the version you’re using) is compatible with CUDA 12.0 and cuDNN 8.2.Instead of using the [and-cuda] extra, you should install TensorFlow directly for GPU support using the pre-built TensorFlow GPU package.Install TensorFlow directly, which should automatically handle the necessary dependencies. pip install tensorflow.

If you encounter issues related to CUDA and cuDNN versions:Verify that the CUDA and cuDNN versions match the TensorFlow version you are using. The TensorFlow compatibility guide  provides specific versions for each TensorFlow release.
